# Repeating a string using a for loop

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I'm fairly new to programming. I'm trying to repeat the word in a given string the amount of times by a given number in the same string. I have decided to loop through the string and add each char to a new string to print out but I'm  getting an out of index error.

```java
final String string = "Hello";
final int num = 3;

int number = string.length() * num;
String str = "";

for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    str += string.charAt(i);
}

System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solve. Noted and I will take in for future code.

Comment: An example of input and output would improve this Question.

Comment: By the way, the `char` type in Java is obsolete. Unable to handle even half the characters defined in Unicode. Learn to use Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep it simple

```java
String string = "Hello";
int num = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

If you want to have your result in a new `String` you can just do this :

```java
String string = "Hello";
int num = 3;
String res = "";
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    res += string;
}
System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: I didn't realise I could just add the original string to the new one instead of trying to add each char that I looped through. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## Zero-based index

You are getting the error because the value of `i` is going beyond the last index available in `Hello`. The last index in `Hello` is `"Hello".length() - 1` whereas the value of `i` is going beyond this value because of your loop terminating condition:

```
i < string.length() *  num;
```

By the way, if you want to repeat `Hello` 3 times, you should do it as

```
for(int i = 0; i < num; i ++){
   System.out.print(string);
}
```

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String string = "Hello";
        final int num = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            System.out.print(string);
        }
    }
}
```

## `String#repeat`

With Java 11+, you can do it without using a loop by using [`String#repeat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)):

```
System.out.println(string.repeat(num));
```

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String string = "Hello";
        final int num = 3;
        System.out.println(string.repeat(num));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining why i was getting out of index error. That really helped me to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this in here since you stated you're learning.
Java has a [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class, super easy to use

And according this this induvial class using StringBuilder is incredibly more efficient than concatenate.

[StringBuilder vs String concatenation in toString() in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java)